# Setting ACL with spaces in role names in GeoServer's REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I have two roles: `ROLE_FOO` and `ROLE_FOO BAR`.

If I set ACL for a workspace using the web admin UI the resulting rule in `security/layers.properties` is `workspace.*.r=ROLE_FOO,ROLE_FOO BAR`.

If I send `<rules><rule resource="workspace.*.r">ROLE_FOO,ROLE_FOO BAR</rule></rules>` via the `security/acl/layers` API though, the result is `workspace.*.r=ROLE_FOO,BAR,ROLE_FOO`.

Evidently the space in the role name is not handled correctly.

How do I send a role ACL setting via the API if there are spaces involved in role names?

---

I tried encoding it with `%20`, surrounding the role name with single quotes, no success.

https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/rest/api/accesscontrol.html only mentions slashes, and it looks like the context of that info is for deletions only.